# How i make a shortcode from this code

Tags: shortcode

im trying to change this code into a shortcode because the method that im using right now is calling the whole file instead, and it a bit slow.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * @package GeneratePress
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header(); 
?>

<div class="testttt">
    <div class="containertest">
        <div class="scroll">
<?php // Get the taxonomy's terms
$terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'job_empresas',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
       
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                <img class="no-lazzy" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($term->term_id, array(200, 200));  ?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-inner">
                    <h3 class="text text-title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
                    <div class="ofertas-company">Ofertas disponibles: <?php echo $term->count ?></div>
                    <input class="company-button" type="button" value="Ver ofertas" onclick="location.href='<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>'">
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    const scroll = document.querySelector(".scroll");
var isDown = false;
var scrollX;
var scrollLeft;

// Mouse Up Function
scroll.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    isDown = false;
    scroll.classList.remove("active");
});

// Mouse Leave Function
scroll.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    isDown = false;
    scroll.classList.remove("active");
});

// Mouse Down Function
scroll.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = true;
    scroll.classList.add("active");
    scrollX = e.pageX - scroll.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = scroll.scrollLeft;
});

// Mouse Move Function
scroll.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = e.pageX - scroll.offsetLeft;
    var scrolling = (element - scrollX) * 2;
    scroll.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scrolling;
});

</script>
```

Comment: What is that file and how are you loading it? I'm not so sure it makes sense to turn an entire page template into a single shortcode, and I don't see how this would speed up your site

Comment: @TomJNowell i created a shortcode to load the file, whiche basically have html and script in it, i want to load it just in certain page with a shortcode directly, without the need to load file. is for pagespeed.

Comment: can you include the rest of your code? By pagespeed do you mean google pagespeed? Or performance? Or both? This question is incomplete, add as much information as you can as well as the missing code by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

To make the inteire file a shortcode its at least something to considered, for that I would call the page instead.  However a short code can be done like this. paste it in your functions.php

```php
if (! function_exists('my_custom_shortcode_with_the_name_I_had_choosen')) {
  function my_custom_shortcode_with_the_name_I_had_choosen(){
     ... your code ....
  }
}

add_shortcode('whatever_name', 'my_custom_shortcode_with_the_name_I_had_choosen');
```

to a few more information check for example this.
https://torquemag.io/2017/06/custom-shortcode/